# Difference between Any and generic type

Tags: scala

I have seen this function. I created this function with generic types but I saw this solution. I don't know if type the args with Any is better or there's different.

```
def flatten(ls: List[Any]): List[Any] = ls flatMap {
    case ms: List[_] => flatten(ms)
    case e => List(e)
  }
```

or

```
def flatten(ls: List[A]): List[A]
```

Comment: `Any` is a type that should never appear in an ordinary, idiomatic Scala code.

Answer (score 7):

One of the differences is, when you take `Any`, you lose all type information, however with generics, you still have a notion of the type.

For example, if you have a function of `(Any) => Any`, you can take any type and return any type.

With generic you could however restrict that if you take an instance of `T` you must also return an instance of `T`, as `(T) => T`.

Using generics will enable the compiler to help you check that you infact does return a `List[T]`.